# How to make a multi-threaded chat system with python socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, python-sockets

I am making a chat system, and currently, I can only send messages one at a time. I was told this was because my chat server is single-threaded, which makes sense.

Can someone please produce some pseudo-code to help me understand how to make a multi-threaded chat?

Here is the server code:

```
import socket
serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serv.bind(("", 8080))
serv.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = serv.accept()

    print("Connection recieved from", addr)
    while True:
        strig = str(input("Enter your message to the client: "))
        c.send(strig.encode())

        thing = c.recv(1024)
        message = list(str(thing))
        message.remove("b")
        printable = ""

        for item in message:
            printable += item
        print(printable)

        strig = str(input("Enter your message to the client: "))
        c.send(strig.encode())

        thing = c.recv(1024)
        message = list(str(thing))
        message.remove("b")
        printable = ""

        for item in message:
            printable += item
        print(printable)
```

Here is the client code:

```
import socket
from time import sleep
s = socket.socket()

port = 8080

s.connect(("10.0.0.92", port))
while True:
    thing = str(s.recv(1024))
    message = list(thing)
    message.remove("b")
    #message.remove("/")
    printable = ""
    for item in message:
        printable += item
    print(printable)

    your = str(input("Enter your message to the server: "))
    s.send(your.encode())

    thing = str(s.recv(1024))
    message = list(thing)
    message.remove("b")
    #message.remove("/")
    printable = ""
    for item in message:
        printable += item
    print(printable)

    your = str(input("Enter your message to the server: "))
    s.send(your.encode())
```

Thanks in advance!!

p.s. I want one of the people to be the server, and one to be the client. Please don't tell me to make them both clients.

Comment: BTW, please give me pseudo code to help me understand how to make a multi-threaded chat server. I am a noob at sockets, and I only started 2 days ago. Thanks!!

Comment: _Can someone please produce some pseudo-code to help me understand how to make a multi-threaded chat?_ Stack Overflow is not a tutorial resource, do you have a specific question? Please see [ask], [tour], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Actually, StackOverflow, as far as I am concerned, is a resource for learning. I am simply asking a question, and I am sure someone will answer.

Comment: _Therefore all questions are allowed, as long as they involve learning?_ Yes, I believe so.

Comment: You believe wrong.  Read [ask].  Read the [threading module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), make an attempt, and if you get stuck, post the problem you are having as a [mcve].  If you want me to design the whole thing for you, $100/hr.

Comment: 100$ per hour? Ridiculous! I am sure someone will produce pseudo code!

Comment: I figured it out myself.

Comment: Also, I looked through the How to Ask thing, and there is nothing in there that doesn't allow asking for psuedo code. I have also produced an example of what I have tried, and I have looked through the threading module docs prior to asking this question. I asked this question as a last resort, and I wasn't expecting such curtness.

Comment: @AMC and, I looked through all of the rules of SO, and nowhere does it say that SO is not a tutorial resource. Just saying.

Comment: @KappagantulaChandrasekhar BTW, The above users are correct.